# Расширение хром. Как вернуть масив в окно расширения?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Заинтересовался расширением для хрома. ПОявилась необходимость собрать адреса всех картинок без атрибута альт и вывести в окне расширения. 
Для работы использую данный скрипт. Но как можно сделать так, чтобы в окно возвращался масив arr? Мне приходит только Null

```
var arr = [];
$('img').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).attr('alt') || $(this).attr('alt') == ''){    
      arr.push($(this).attr('src')+'\n\r');
  }
});
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Где вы исполняете данные код? Это должен быть [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Код из примера исполняется прямо в консоли. Мне нужно вернуть масив arr в расширение для работы с ним.

Comment: Консоль сайта и расширения виртуально разделены. Вы так и планируете выполнять в консоли или будет автоматизировано? Если автоматизировано, то вам нужен content-script как и было упомянуто.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы так нажимать скрипты, выбери своё расширение (где я выбрал адблок на фоточке) в консоли
[image: консоль]

А вообще, так дела не делаются, [вот так](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) - делаются. Гугли уроки, разбирай примеры экстетов с контент скриптами. Настраиваешь один раз подключение, библиотеки(Jq), потом чтоб потестить жмешь круглую стрелку здесь: `chrome://extensions/`

Либо если хочешь запускать *для теста / по быстрому* кастом скрипты.. используй [этот экстет](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka)

+Несколько замечаний по коду:

1. var/function больше не используются (смотреть в сторону [ES6](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/))
2. во втором условии используй тройное равно (и забудь про двойное, гугли разницу)
3. Зачем пушить `\r\n` в массив, *не понимаю* (можешь чекать `console.log`ом каждую строку, я серьезно)